# How to Expose non HTTP traffic with Service Type Load Balancer in EKS?

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I need to expose an Apache ActiveMQ pod, to systems outside of the cluster. I am able to get a Network Load Balancer provisioned, but traffic never appears to pass through to the pod.  Using the Service DNS directly, works as expected.

NLB created.

```
❯ kubectl get svc amq-jls-dev-mq -n jls-dev
NAME             TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP                                                                         PORT(S)                                                         AGE
amq-jls-dev-mq   LoadBalancer   172.20.69.156   xxx.elb.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com   8161:32071/TCP,61616:32509/TCP,5672:31654/TCP,61613:30383/TCP   5m38s
```

Its an internal NLB, and im tunneled into the VPC

```
dig +short xxx.elb.us-gov-west-1.amazonaws.com
10.1.5.0
```

Attempting to use the NLB's IP, Nothing happens

```
❯ pipenv run python -m stomp -V -H 10.1.5.0 -P 61613
Sending {cmd=STOMP,headers=[{'accept-version': '1.1'}],body=}
```

Disable my tunnel into the VPC, and just port forward the service

```
❯ kubectl port-forward --namespace=jls-dev service/amq-jls-dev-mq 61613:61613
Forwarding from 127.0.0.1:61613 -> 61613
Forwarding from [::1]:61613 -> 61613
Handling connection for 61613
```

Repeat Test and it works.

```
❯ pipenv run python -m stomp -V -H localhost -P 61613
Sending {cmd=STOMP,headers=[{'accept-version': '1.1'}],body=}
CONNECTED
server: ActiveMQ/5.17.4
heart-beat: 0,0
session: ID:amq-jls-dev-0-45419-1680110010366-3:1
version: 1.1
```

Its like im missing something.

My annotations

```
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-scheme: internal
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-type: nlb
```

And the service itself

```
spec:
  allocateLoadBalancerNodePorts: true
  clusterIP: 172.20.69.156
  clusterIPs:
  - 172.20.69.156
  externalTrafficPolicy: Local
  healthCheckNodePort: 30744
  internalTrafficPolicy: Cluster
  ipFamilies:
  - IPv4
  ipFamilyPolicy: SingleStack
  ports:
  - name: http
    nodePort: 32071
    port: 8161
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: http
  - name: openwire
    nodePort: 32509
    port: 61616
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: openwire
  - name: amqp
    nodePort: 31654
    port: 5672
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: amqp
  - name: stomp
    nodePort: 30383
    port: 61613
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: stomp
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: amq-jls-dev
    app.kubernetes.io/name: amq
  sessionAffinity: None
  type: LoadBalancer
```